# Java кодом кликнуть на кнопку в браузере

Tags: java, веб-программирование

Как с помощью кода в яве делать операции на странице в браузере?

Например, проводятся какие-то логические вычисления, и в зависимости от результата, который мы получим, нажимается нужная кнопка на странице.

Comment: java или javascript всё же?

Comment: просто в яве. нужно сделать оконную программу.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно использовать `WebView` из JavaFX для загрузки страницы и с помощью `WebEngine` вызвать скрипт на JavaScript.

```
webEngine.executeScript("...click()");
```

Туториал можно посмотреть здесь: http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/webview/jfxpub-webview.htm